# What is the difference between $E(F_p) $ and $F_p[X] / (Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B)$?

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

To try to put into words and what I was thinking.

I was wonder what is the difference between an elliptic curve defined over $F_p : E(F_p)$

And the quotient field which is defined by F_p over an elliptic curve equation. Is this a quotient field : $F_p[X] / (Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B)$?

What I believe I know is this:

$E(F_p)$ : The number of points in this set is found by using schoofs algorithm.

$F_p[X] / (Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B)$ : The number of points in this set is $p^3$ , 3 because an elliptic curves highest degree is 3.

Therefore, they are not the same.

Maybe there are more things which I am missing?

I am thinking that $F_p[X] / (Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B)$ is the same as just saying $F_p[X] / X^3$

Comment: You probably want $\Gamma(E)=\Bbb{F}_p[X,Y]/(X^3+AX+B-Y^2)$. That is a quotient ring of a polynomial ring in **two** variables, $X$ and $Y$. For $Y^2$ does not make sense as an element of $\Bbb{F}_p[X]$.

Comment: That $\Gamma(E)$ is the [coordinate ring of $E$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateRing.html). The ring of polynomial functions from $E$ to $\Bbb{F}_p$. It can be viewed as a free rank 3 module over $\Bbb{F}_p[Y]$ by reducing the higher powers of $X$ modulo $X^3+AX+B-Y^2$, or as a free rank 2 module over $\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ by reducing higher powers of $Y$ modulo the equation of the curve.